# Add item to a list, without effect

Tags: c#, list, getter

In a C# class I have a list and two different getters for the list:

```
private List<A> a;
public List<A> EveryA
   {
      get
      {
          if (a == null) a = new List<A>();
          return a;
      }
   }
public List<A> FilteredA
   {
       get
       {
          return EveryA.FindAll(a => a.IsInFilter);
       }
    }
```

Now my question is: how about the syntax `FilteredA.Add(this);`?
It compiles and runs but it cannot add any item to any list.
Should a better compiler have to notify the (small) problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not the same list. This is not something the compiler can check for you, since the compiler can't really read your mind. Check the documentation for [`List<T>.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx)

The result is a list, but it isn't the same list (how could it be? your original list isn't filtered!).

You should be able to add items to the list returned by `FilteredA`, except they won't show up in `a`.

I suggest you use LINQs `Where` instead, returning an `IEnumerable<T>`. That way, it is obvious that the result of `FilteredA` shouldn't be changed, only iterated over:

```
public IEnumerable<A> FilteredA
{
    get { return EveryA.Where(a => a.IsInFilter); }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the linq suggestion, and if I could, + another 1 for "the compiler can't really read your mind."

Comment: The suggestion of IEnumerable is really useful and elegant, I'll have to remember that. However the suggestion to use Linq doesn't make as much sense to me; I don't see the difference with the predicate in my example code?

Comment: with "Linq", I just mean the extension methods provided in `System.Linq`, i.e. `Where`. There is no difference with the predicate in your example, in fact, I reused your predicate. The difference is is only that the Linq version uses lazy evaluation. You could still use your version and just change the return type. I just never thought of that...

Answer (score 3):

No. Why should it notify you about this? It is completely ok.
`FilteredA` doesn't return `a` but a new instance of a `List<A>`.
`FilteredA.Add(this);` adds `this` to this new instance.

See this code:

```
var filteredA = FilteredA;
int count1 = filteredA.Count;
filteredA.Add(this);
int count2 = filteredA.Count;
Assert.AreEqual(count1 + 1, count2);
```

This shows, that the new item IS added to the list. But to that new instance that is independent of the list inside your class.

Answer (score 3):

FindAll returns a new list. You're adding the new item to the new list but not retaining a reference to the new list, I suppose. The semantics would be clearer if the filtered list came from a method rather than a property.

Comment: I agree, FilteredA should be a Method/Function, not a Property.

Comment: Why would a method result in a more clear semantics? And - when the property returns IEnmerable instead of List, should it in your opinion still be a method (and if so, why)?

Comment: A property implies something fairly static; it should always return the same thing, for two separate calls (unless someone wrote to the property between the calls, of course). Properties with getter side effects (other than those related to reading the property, perhaps, like logging, or lazy loading) are confusing, as in this case, where you, the author of the code, were confused. A method called GetFilteredA() looks more like it is capable of creating a new object with every call. And yes, the IEnumerable-returning approach should also be a method.

Comment: To elaborate: I searched Google for *Methods vs Properties* and the first hit was http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wwfsses(v=vs.80).aspx, which says in part "In general, properties store data for an object, and methods are actions an object can be asked to perform." So a property getter is focused on retrieving data (the underlying list), while the requirement for this member is to perform an action (filtering the list) and return the result.

Answer (score 2):

`public List<A> FilteredA` returns some output of the `FindAll` method, as a `List<A>`. This will not be the same object as `EveryA` so when it goes out of scope your addition will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a compiler issue - since the code is valid it will compile just fine. The problem is more on a code quality level. To catch something like this, you could use a tool like [FxCop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop) to analyze your code.

Both methods can be seen as query methods. You should not expose the result as a List, but rather an IEnumerable or A[]. If you want to add an item to the list, do so with an Add method.

```
private List<A> items = new List<A>();

public IEnumerable<A> EveryA
{
  get { return items; }
}

public IEnumerable<A> FilteredA
{
  get { return items.Where(item => item.IsInFilter); }
}

public void AddItem(A item)
{
  items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. Still I slightly prefer the public List<A> EveryA, probably also a matter of taste?